# Error installing SQL Server Management Studio 17.6 , 18.5 code : 0x800b0003:

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I had SQL Server Management Studio v17.6 and uninstall it; now I want to install version v18.6.

But I can't. I get an error 0x800b0003.

Even though I tried v17.6 version again, I'm still getting the same error.

I already tried all these solutions and I don't know what is wrong:

[enter link description here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/34f91307-810b-42b2-85cd-c36dcf731a71/setup-failed-ms-sql-serve)

- Windows 10 1909
- SQL Server 2019 installed

Error log

```
[22BC:14A4][2021-01-06T22:41:19]i000: MainViewModel.OnBundleAction: Bundle action started
[2468:03DC][2021-01-06T22:41:19]i360: Creating a system restore point.
[2468:03DC][2021-01-06T22:41:21]i361: Created a system restore point.
[2468:03DC][2021-01-06T22:41:21]i000: Caching bundle from: 'C:\Users\Key1-lab\AppData\Local\Temp\        {29fdeb7a-f6e5-40c3-a203-e306837e95a4}\.be\SSMS-Setup-ENU.exe' to: 'C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\        {29fdeb7a-f6e5-40c3-a203-e306837e95a4}\SSMS-Setup-ENU.exe'
[2468:03DC][2021-01-06T22:41:21]i320: Registering bundle dependency provider: {29fdeb7a-f6e5-40c3-a203-e306837e95a4}, version: 15.0.18369.0
[2468:2DB4][2021-01-06T22:41:24]e000: Error 0x800b0003: Failed authenticode verification of payload:     C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\HelpViewer2_3
[2468:2DB4][2021-01-06T22:41:24]e000: Error 0x800b0003: Failed to verify signature of payload:     HelpViewer2_3
[2468:2DB4][2021-01-06T22:41:24]e310: Failed to verify payload: HelpViewer2_3 at path:     C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\HelpViewer2_3, error: 0x800b0003. Deleting file.
[2468:2DB4][2021-01-06T22:41:24]e000: Error 0x800b0003: Failed to cache payload: HelpViewer2_3
[22BC:3124][2021-01-06T22:41:24]e314: Failed to cache payload: HelpViewer2_3 from working path:     C:\Users\Key1-lab\AppData\Local\Temp\{29fdeb7a-f6e5-40c3-a203-e306837e95a4}\HelpViewer2_3, error:     0x800b0003.
[22BC:3124][2021-01-06T22:41:24]e349: Application requested retry of payload: HelpViewer2_3,     encountered error: 0x800b0003. Retrying...
[2468:2DB4][2021-01-06T22:41:27]e000: Error 0x800b0003: Failed authenticode verification of payload:     C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\HelpViewer2_3
[2468:2DB4][2021-01-06T22:41:27]e000: Error 0x800b0003: Failed to verify signature of payload: HelpViewer2_3
[2468:2DB4][2021-01-06T22:41:27]e310: Failed to verify payload: HelpViewer2_3 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\HelpViewer2_3, error: 0x800b0003. Deleting file.
[2468:2DB4][2021-01-06T22:41:27]e000: Error 0x800b0003: Failed to cache payload: HelpViewer2_3
[22BC:3124][2021-01-06T22:41:27]e314: Failed to cache payload: HelpViewer2_3 from working path:     C:\Users\Key1-lab\AppData\Local\Temp\{29fdeb7a-f6e5-40c3-a203-e306837e95a4}\HelpViewer2_3, error:     0x800b0003.
[22BC:3124][2021-01-06T22:41:27]e349: Application requested retry of payload: HelpViewer2_3, encountered error: 0x800b0003. Retrying...
[2468:2DB4][2021-01-06T22:41:31]e000: Error 0x800b0003: Failed authenticode verification of payload:     C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\HelpViewer2_3
[2468:2DB4][2021-01-06T22:41:31]e000: Error 0x800b0003: Failed to verify signature of payload:     HelpViewer2_3
[2468:2DB4][2021-01-06T22:41:31]e310: Failed to verify payload: HelpViewer2_3 at path:     C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\HelpViewer2_3, error: 0x800b0003. Deleting file.
[2468:2DB4][2021-01-06T22:41:31]e000: Error 0x800b0003: Failed to cache payload: HelpViewer2_3
[22BC:3124][2021-01-06T22:41:31]e314: Failed to cache payload: HelpViewer2_3 from working path:     C:\Users\Key1-lab\AppData\Local\Temp\{29fdeb7a-f6e5-40c3-a203-e306837e95a4}\HelpViewer2_3, error:     0x800b0003.
[22BC:14A4][2021-01-06T22:41:32]e000: Error 0x800b0003: Failed while caching, aborting execution.
[2468:03DC][2021-01-06T22:41:32]i330: Removed bundle dependency provider: {29fdeb7a-f6e5-40c3-a203-    e306837e95a4}
[2468:03DC][2021-01-06T22:41:32]i352: Removing cached bundle: {29fdeb7a-f6e5-40c3-a203-e306837e95a4},     from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{29fdeb7a-f6e5-40c3-a203-e306837e95a4}\
[22BC:14A4][2021-01-06T22:41:32]e000: MainViewModel.OnBundleAction: Bundle action failed: The form     specified for the subject is not one supported or known by the specified trust provider (0x800B0003)
[22BC:14A4][2021-01-06T22:41:32]i399: Apply complete, result: 0x800b0003, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No
[22BC:2DFC][2021-01-06T22:41:36]i000: MainViewModel.OpenUrl: Opening url: C:\Users\Key1-lab\AppData\Local\Temp\SsmsSetup\SSMS-Setup-ENU_20210106224114.log
```

Comment: did you delete those folder on that link you sent

Comment: yes i did actuly there was no such a folder .

Comment: `Failed authenticode verification of payload` ... have you installed all pending Windows Updates, including any required reboots? It sounds like you're missing some Microsoft Root Authority certificates.

Comment: you mean i should update windows to 2004 version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at your update section in windows see if there are any update
and do those update

Comment: just updated from  1909 to 2004 and now just installed mssm 18.6 successfully. tnx just saved my day